# Instantiating class from return value of property getter

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework

I came across some weird behavior today around creating an object from the return value of a getter method.

Firstly I tried this

```
$productMapper = new $this->getDbMapper();
```

Which gives me an undefined property: $getDbMapper error.

From what it looks like, it's trying to access $getDbMapper as class property and then using the `()` for the class instantiation rather than as the method (?).

I also have this issue in a another section of code with where the class takes a constructor argument.

Would this be a good time to look at some kind of factory pattern over the top or am I just missing something?

Comment: Does `$productMapper = new $this->{getDbMapper()};` work? Also, can you set up a CodePad or something showing the problem?

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant getDbMapper - assumed 'getDbMapper' in

Comment: As i can see the solution in your question: Whats the problem?

Comment: Because it just creates unnecessary variables, and was looking for an explanation as to why the first line of code isn't valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix, which I'm not particularly happy with

```
$mapper = $this->getDbMapper();
$productMapper = new $mapper();

// With a class constructor
$form = $this->getForm();
$form = new $form($productData);
```